# how to correct the layout in order to make it flexible and responsive?

Tags: html, css, angular

hello this my angular application i aim to have a responsive page despite using col and row i didn't get the result i want this my html :

```css
.red {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  height: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: green;
}

.bleu {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 red ">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10  bleu">
    <h1> overview </h1>
    <div class=" row green"> block </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col block">
        block1
      </div>
      <div class="col block ">
        block2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this the result I want to get [image]

the block1 and 2 have the same size . in each part i'm going to add later my component.

And here is the corresponding [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-c6hhvw)

Comment: You did not write the `row` class in CSS. You could for example implement it as `.row { display: flex}` and add a `flex:1` in the `blue` class

Comment: SO far I only see a grid layout. What does responsive mean to you? I miss any indicators or details about a `responsive layout part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstrap, you forgot to add `col` class. See below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-2 red ">sidebar</div>
  <div class="col col-md-10  bleu">
    <h1> overview </h1>
    <div class="row green"> block </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col block">block1</div>
      <div class="col block ">block2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no that doesn't work for me i just want the same result as the picture

Comment: Are you using any framework? is it bootstrap?